# Actions class for mouseover?

Tags: webdriver

I want to mousover in order to click a menu item that appears. I read about the Actions class to use

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
```

However it doesn't work for me because I get type or namespace not found. 
I am importing

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
```

to your import list. It's a little surprising that Visual Studio's Intellisense didn't pick this up for you, but that should get you on your way.

Comment: thanks that helped, but now similar issue further down the line. Says it can't resolve moveToElement or perform. var builder = new Actions(_driver); Actions hover = builder.moveToElement(settingMenu); hover.perform;

Comment: That's because moveToElement is the Java bindings method. In .NET, it's MoveToElement. Note the initial capital letter. The .NET API uses PascalCase method names to remain consistent with other libraries and the Framework itself. The Java bindings use camelCase, as is common for that language.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am able to hover now